# Multiple checkbox search filter using react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to create multiple checkbox search filter in my react-redux application.

I have added checkboxes, which will make request to api, but the issue is, every time when I clicked on checkbox, new data is coming from api, which is overwriting old data in the state.

How can I retain my old state ? or Is there any other way to do this ?

This is my reducer

```
 import * as types from '../constants';
 const InitialState = { data: [], };
 export const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => 
 { 
    switch(action.type) {
     case types.GET_DATA:
       return Object.assign({}, state, {data:action.payload.data });
     default: 
       return state;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: If you are doing it using redux it should retain state. Anyway post some code so that people can help

Comment: What's your state tree look like? Update your question with an example of how your state tree is structured.

Comment: import * as types from '../constants';

const InitialState =  {
   data: [],
};

export  const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case types.GET_DATA:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {data:action.payload.data });
     default:
  return state;
 }
}

This is my reducer.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Post the code where you think problem is or upload minimal version of your project on github.

Comment: Can you please tell me why data is getting overwritten in the state ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear in the question as to *how* you want to keep the old data while still fetching new data, but given that data is an array, I'll assume you mean you want to merge them.

```
export const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => 
{
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.GET_DATA:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {data: [...state.data, ...action.payload.data] });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This is making the assumption that you can always just append the new data.  If not you will need to be more selective about which items get merged into the array before assigning it to the state.

```
export const dataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => 
{
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.GET_DATA:
            let data = [...action.payload.data]

            // merge in the relevant items from state.data, e.g.
            for (let item in state.data.filter(it => it.shouldBeKept)) {
                data.push(item)
            }

            return Object.assign({}, state, { data });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you will know best how to identify the items to keep or not, modify the logic hear to best suit your need.  For example, it might make morse sense for you to start with `let data = [...state.data]` and selectively merge items from `action.payload.data`, or to start with an empty array and pick and choose from either arrays.  **The important part is that you construct a new array, and not add items to the existing array in the state.**

Comment: if I do [...state.data, ...action.payload.data], I'm getting empty array.

Comment: It shouldn't be... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_way_to_concatenate_arrays